# Functional equation with periods depending on $f$

Tags: contest-math, functional-equations, periodic-functions

Find all functions $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=f(x+y+f(y))$ for any $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ and $f(0)=-1$.

I suspect that the only solution is $f(x)=-1$. It is easy to see that we can reformulate that $y+f(y)$ is a period of the function. If we would know that this is a surjective function or its image contains an interval we would be done . Unfortunately not much can be said about it.

Note: It is false without an extra assumption like continuity. See example below.

Comment: FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24f(x)%3Df(x%2By%2Bf(y))%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24f(0)%3D-1%24&p=1), I found the somewhat similar AoPS thread [Functional Equation](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1881402p12802809), where its functional equation is $f(x)=f(x+y-f(y))$, with the condition $f(0)=0$, plus the additional requirement that $f(x)$ is continuous.

Comment: Requiring $f$ to be continuous makes the problem  easy that is why I have not mentioned it. I think you can show that every rational number has to be a period. I am interested in this more general statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(not an answer, but the picture won't fit in a comment)

This will do as well.

[image: graph]

Comment: Great! I was hoping that a construction would work to give a counterexample.